# Is this way of saving true/false options in JavaScript efficient?

Tags: javascript, performance, binary, storage

In some places, you'll see options saved as numbers. For example, when setting file permissions, you pass them using a value ranging from 0 to 7 for each group of users.
Each one of the bits in the binary representation of the number represents one of three permissions: read, write and execute, so a value of 7, with a binary representation of 111 means that the file can be read, written and executed, whereas a value of 5 means that the file can only be read and executed because of the binary representation 101.

*side note: I'm not an expert on how operating systems manage files; my explanation may be wrong, but I'm sure that the basic idea of binary numbers representing these options is implemented there.*

I am now wondering if it is efficient to store true/false options in binary using JavaScript. To do so, I would create the JavaScript as follows:

```
function OptionsGenerator(){
    //this method takes a number, and returns an array of options.
    this.num2options = function(num){
        var str,len,opts=[];
        if(typeof num !== "number") return false;
        str = num.toString(2);
        len = str.length;
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
            opts[i] = (str.charAt(i)==="1") ? true : false;
        }
        return opts;
    }
    //this function gets an array of options, and returns a number.
    this.options2num = function(opts){
        var str = "",o,opt;
        for(o in options){
            opt = (options[o]) ? 1 : 0;
            str+=opt;
        }
        return parseInt(str,2);
    }
    //this function returns a specific option with an index ranging from 1 to the number of options set. takes 2 arguments: the first one is the set of options. This can either be a number or a string containing a binary representation of the number, the second parameter contains the index of the option.
    this.getOption = function(num,optnum){
        var str;
        if(typeof num === 'number')
            str = num.toString(2);
        else
            str = num;
       return (num.charAt(optnum-1)==="1");
    }
}
```

My question is: is this an efficient way to save options, and if it is, is there a more efficient way to convert from binary to a number, and to get a specific option, or all the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to accomplish something similar in JavaScript, I would recommend actually using bitwise operators, namely & and |.

For example:

```
var read = 1;
var write = 2;
var execute = 4;

var rw = read | write;

var someUserPermission = 3;  // or, var someUserPermission = read & write;

// can read? 
console.log((someUserPermission & read) === read); // => true
console.log((someUserPermission & write) === write); // => true
console.log((someUserPermission & execute) === execute); // => false
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `rw = read | write` ? As read in binary would be "01", and write would be "10", read & write would cancel eachother out as none of the bit pairs are both 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just store them as an array.  This looks like a waste of time.  You've seen options stored like that since they were used to 'mask' things.

Answer (score 0):

whether or not this is efficient way to store options depends on the area where you are going to use it. If you are creating a plugin and exposing this to the user so as to initialize your plugin using this method, it may confuse him/her.